# Why is $U(n,n)= GL(2n, \mathbb{C}) \cap O(2n,2n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

I have read the statement above. I tried to prove it but I could not. For me, $O(2n,2n)$ already a subgroup of $GL(2n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Should it be $SL(2n,\mathbb C)$?

Comment: It appeared in the thesis of M. Gualtieri http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401221 page 43, proposition 4.6. I have checked again but it is written as $GL(2n,\mathbb{C})$. Also I have read in the thesis of Baraglia http://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/37984/1/02whole.pdf page 44.

Comment: This should be a comment: A similar (but easier) result is proved as Lemma 2.19 on page 44 in Salamon-McDuff's Introduction to symplectic topology: http://books.google.com/books?id=DNjKAeRexE4C&pg=PA44. I suppose your problem can be solved entirely analogously if you spell out the definitions properly.

Comment: @axblount No. In a unitary group, the norm of the determinant of a matrix is 1, i.e. $|\det(U)|=1$. But in general it does not have to be equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, $O(2n,2n)$ is a group of $4n$-by-$4n$ matrices, so both $GL(2n,\mathbb C)$ and $U(n,n)$ would need to be mapped to $GL(4n,\mathbb R)$. This is not a problem, though can cause some cognitive dissonance. Any choice of isomorphism $\mathbb C^{2n}\rightarrow\mathbb R^{4n}$ will do, giving imbeddings to $GL(4n,\mathbb R)$.

A common trick with classical groups is the following: let $(,)$ be the hermitian form of signature $n,n$ left invariant by $U(n,n)$. Let $\langle u,v\rangle=\Re(u,v)$ be the real part. Using our chosen isomorphism $\mathbb C^{2n}\rightarrow \mathbb R^{4n}$ gives a symmetric $\mathbb R$-valued from $\langle,\rangle$ on $\mathbb R^{4n}$. By design, the image of $U(n,n)$ preserves $\langle,\rangle$. Also, the signature of $\langle,\rangle$ is simply "double" that of $(,)$, so is $2n,2n$.

Thus, for simple reasons $U(n,n)$ injects *to* $O(2n,2n)$. Then a dimension-count (looking at the Lie algebra) shows that the dimensions are equal, so at least the connected components of the identity are the same.